# How to score the Southampton to New York route in Ticket to Ride UK?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, scoring, ticket-to-ride-united-kingdom

In Ticket to Ride UK, when the Southampton to New York route is claimed, does the claimant receive the points for laying down train cars in addition to the 40 points stated on the board?

If so, how many points do they get?

Answer (score 7):

Nothing extra. 40 points is the amount gained for a 10-car route.

---

The progression of the number of points earned per car is roughly linear.

```
Length  Points  PerCar  Maps
------  ------  ------  -------------------------------
     1       1    1.00  [Common]
     2       2    1.00  [Common]
     3       4    1.33  [Common]
     4       7    1.75  [Common]
     5      10    2.00  [Common]
     6      15    2.50  [Common]
     7      18    2.57  Germany (x4), Pennsylvania (x1)
     8      21    2.63  Europe (x1), India (x1)
     9      27    3.00  Nordic Countries (x1)
    10      40    4.00  UK (x1)
```

[image: Points Per Car As a Function of Length]

As you can see, getting 40 points for a 10-car route fits the regular progression. It wouldn't make sense for the 40 points to be in addition to the roughly 40 points one would expect to get from just laying down the cars.

Comment: Looking at that graph, if anything 40 points is already higher than might be expected.

Comment: If we assume the points form a line, one would expect 47 points (looking at the trains of length 1..9) or 40 points (looking at the trains of length 2..9). [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3htDK.png)

Answer (score 2):

No. You get 40 points, the largest possible award of points in the game. There is no entry for a 10-wagon route on the points table; there are longer ones, e.g. 18 points for a 7-wagon route on the Pennsylvania map. See comments for more...

Comment: I think the Nordic Countries map has a length 9, 27 pointer on the table and there's a length 8, 21 pointer on the India map.

Comment: The Europe map also has a length 8 route.

Comment: @Jontia, Henrik : You are both correct. I edited my answer to reflect that.